# Tightest bound on the norm of vectors whose distance is bounded

Tags: inequality

Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Assume $||a-b||\leq ||c||$ where $||\cdot||$ is 2-norm. Is there any bound tighter than $||a||^2 \leq 2||b||^2+2||c||^2$ that can bound norm of $a$ in terms of norm squared of other vectors? (the proof is given below)

$$
||a|| - ||b|| \leq ||a-b|| \leq ||c||
$$

$$
||a||^2 \leq (||b|| + ||c||)^2\leq  2||b||^2+2||c||^2
$$

Comment: @Theo Bendit: thank you. I fixed that.

Comment: The tightest bound, in terms of the norms of $a$ and $b$, is $\|a\| \le \|b\| + \|c\|$. This is most definitely tighter than $\|a\|^2 \le 2\|b\|^2 + 2\|c\|^2$.

Comment: @Theo Bendit: Actually, I need the the upper bound in terms of the norm squared. That is why I ended up with the second inequality.

Comment: I could vary it trivially and say that $\|a\|^2 \le (\sqrt{\|b\|^2} + \sqrt{\|c\|^2})^2$; that will be, once again, the tightest possible bound on $\|a\|^2$ as a function of $\|b\|^2$ and $\|c\|^2$. I don't think this question is as well-defined as you might have thought.